# CUPS Changing AuthInfoRequired from username,password to none with https URI

Tags: cups, ipp

I have two CentOS 6 servers running cups and connecting to the same ipp over https printer. Both were installed with the same `lpadmin` command below.

```
lpadmin -p ptr -v https://username%40mailer.com:p%40ssword@myprintserver.com/printer -E
```

Server 1 was able to print without issue.

Cups

```
Name        : cups
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.4.2
Release     : 44.el6
```

printers.conf

```
<Printer ptr>
AuthInfoRequired username,password
Info ptr
DeviceURI https://username%40mailer.com:p%40ssword@myprintserver.com/printer
```

Server 2 is not able to print

Cups

```
Name        : cups
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.4.2
Release     : 78.el6_9
```

printers.conf

```
<Printer ptr>
AuthInfoRequired none
Info ptr
DeviceURI https://username%40mailer.com:p%40ssword@myprintserver.com/printer
```

In `/var/log/cups/error_log`

```
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] Connected to printer...
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] Connected to my-printserverip:443 (IPv4)...
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] Getting supported attributes...
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] ATTR: auth-info-required=none
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] Backend returned status 2 (authentication required)
D [26/Oct/2017:10:31:53 -0400] [Job 220770] Job held for authentication.
```

On Server 2 I tried stoping cups, changing `AuthInfoRequired` from `none` to `username,password` and then starting cups however it doesn't fix it and on the next cups restart just reverts back to `none`. I tried bouncing cups on Server 1 and it retains the `username,password`. I then updated Server 1 to version `78.el6_9`, uninstalling and reinstalling `ptr` with the above lpadmin command and now both servers are in the same boat reverting to `AuthInfoRequired none` and `Job held for authentication`.

Is there something different I need to do with the new version of cups?

I have tried passing `-o auth-info=username,password`, however this appears to make the `AuthInfoRequired` line disappear all together and results in the same errors in the log as above.

Update 1:

Testing with CentOS 7 gives expected behavior of automatically populating `AuthInfoRequired` with `username,password` CUPS version `1.6.3-26`

Update 2:

Tried to `rpmrepack` cups 1.4.2-44 from another CentOS 6 server and rpm downgrade to the prior older version with no success.

Update 3:

I have started reading the cups source code for my version. It appears the AuthInfoRequired field is automatic set for ipp printers based on if cups see's a password in the DeviceURI, not sure why it's tossing my Auth info out the window.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `auth-info=username,password` use `auth-info-required` (eg `-o auth-info-required=username,password`). CUPS rewrites `printers.conf` when stopping (see [the man page](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-printers.conf.html), [CUPS source](https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/5d8b7d2665983396c19b956f5bcf92afd407b2fe/scheduler/server.c#L172)), so to edit the file either stop the CUPS server first or use `lpoptions`.

If you revert to 1.4.2-44 and set `auth-info-required` you should be back to being able to print.